# Rails 3 export csv from partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I followed RBate's [Railscast on the subject](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel), but I have a caviat.

The view starts with a form to define the table's variables. On clicking submit, the form posts back to the same view and re-renders the partial (which is just the HTML table). It's not AJAX, it's all form params.

RBates uses a single variable and calls .to_csv on it. I have a complex table with many variables defined by the params and so don't know how to call .to_csv on the entire HTML table.

I need to be able to export just the results in the partial.

Thanks in advance for the ideas.

&&&&&&&&  AS REQUESTED, SAMPLE CODE:   &&&&&&&&

So, the full code is probably more confusing than helpful, but here's a slimmed down version:

**stats/reporter.html.erb:** (stat_reporter_path matches this URI)

```
<%= form_tag( :stat_reporter, method: :post ) do %>
    form is in here
    <%= submit_tag "Get my report" %>
<% end %>

<div>
    <%= render 'stat_select' %>
</div>
```

**stats/_stat_select:**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>...column heads...</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @counties.each do |c| %>
      <td><%= c.name %></td>
        <% c.programs.each do |p| %>
          <td><%= p.name %></td>
            <% p.events.each do |e| %>
              <td><%= e.name %></td>
...and so on...
</table>
```

Here's a screenshot [image: screenshot]

Comment: how about some example code?

Comment: Done. Just for you @SeamusAbshere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back on this post, I would:

1. Create a link to a new view and pas all the variables to in the URL.
2. That view would use all the variables to create an HTML output that could be used to create the to_csv method
3. Once the csv file was created, the controller would render the original view.